# Where to bump artifact/release version in maven projects

Tags: java, git, maven, release

So am using git, maven and semantic versioning for artifacts (1.0.0 Snapshot / Release)

Lets take for example this [branching model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)   (develop -> release branch -> master)

From best practises point of view.
In which branch should I increment artifact version, when should I bump from 1.x.x snapshot to 1.x.x release. Should 1.x.x release version ever get back to develop branch? and then on the next feature branch to change it back to snapshot?

I am planning to use maven release plugin in the future, but before that, I would like to know the approach. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I do this on the release branch as I'm preparing my release.

Comment: can you be more explicit? Do what? just increasing versions? But when do you change from snapshot to release?

Comment: @UnguruBulan Yes, I meant that I change all of my release strings and numbers on the release branch. I've never differentiated between "snapshot" and "release" in any of my projects.